# Finding the largest of 3 numbers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{ 
    float a, b, c; 
    printf("Enter three numbers: "); 
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c); 
    if (a>=b) 
    { 
        if(a>=c) 
          printf("Largest number = %.2f",a); 
        else 
          printf("Largest number = %.2f",c); 
    }

    else 
    { 
        if(b>=c) 
            printf("Largest number = %.2f",b);
        else printf("Largest number = %.2f",c);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

when I compile. the code will scan for the 3 numbers but wont do anything afterwards. even if i put {} around every if and else statements, it wont change.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/DeW3T4).

Comment: Works like a charm, which compiler are you using? did you forget to press the return key?

Comment: Are you perhaps running this in a window which closes immediately when the program ends?

Comment: @interjay output windows generally don't close immediately until they finish execution, the guy has a scanf statement. So...

Comment: @Pranay What's your point? The window will close after the printfs which could cause OP to think it didn't show anything.

Comment: He said "but wont do anything afterwards"

Comment: @Pranay He already mentioned that his code scans for 3 numbers and then doesn't do anything.

Comment: Your code is fine, but duplicating the same code in different places is something you should try to avoid. See if you can rewrite it so that it only uses one call to `printf()`. Also, it might be a good idea to add a newline character (`\n`) at the end of your output.

Comment: Yep, I'm just sayin, If the asker couldn't see the OP in the window he'd have mentioned the window would have closed right? he said " the code will scan for the 3 numbers but wont do anything afterwards" and not "window closes". Its a wrong assumption to think that asker(s) is/are so dumb.

Comment: @Pranay I guess you haven't seen a lot of questions then because people neglect to mention critical information all the time. Especially people like OP here who don't even respond to comments.

Comment: My money is on @squeamish ossifrage.  Add `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

As Shubham suggested, try putting something at the end of the program that prevents the windows command line interface from closing instantly.

A [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) from `stdio.h` is more appropriate than `getch()` from conio, because it's in the standard library.

If you run the program from a command line interface and not by double clicking the icon or hitting the run-button in the IDE your program runs fine without the `getchar()`, as you would expect.

You can also check if your IDE supports an option to leave the command line interface open after the program has terminated.

Another option is setting a breakpoint on the last line of your `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `getch()` before the `return 0` statement. Don't forget to `#include <conio.h>`.
What is happening is that the program displays the result and closes immediately.

**EDIT:**
Assuming you are on windows

Comment: conio.h is not available on many platforms.

Comment: i think this is what was missing, I was doing a draft with  Dev-C++, then tried putting it into my actual program "unix" which is very terrible. after fooling around adding {} it seemed to work out fine

Answer (score 0):

you have include one more header file like   **conio.h** . you may aware of this one....sorry to remember you this basic header file for output window.......then before your **return 0;** line just write  **getch();**

Sample like:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>
```

int main()

```
{ 

  /* your code to check conditions for which number is greater among these numbers  */

  getch();

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend getchar() or getc() from <stdio.h> rather than including conio.h. Using conio.h makes your program less portable, and in this case there's no reason it shouldn't be (with regards to "who cares if it's portable, it just finds the minimum!", it's better to get into these habits now than later)